# Checking the generic rank of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra, algorithms, computer-algebra

Suppose that $A,B\in M_{p,q}(\mathbb{Z})$ are two rectangular integer matrices of the same size. Suppose that one has a conjecture stating that the rank of the matrix $A+tB$ for Zariski generic values of $t$ is equal to $r$. Is there a way to check that conjecture that is more efficient than the "obvious way" (compute the Smith normal form or Hermite normal form in $\mathbb{Q}[t]$)? Thing is, the "obvious way" does much more: it tells us what values are non-generic, so I am wondering if there is some sneaky way to do less for getting less. (If it helps, the matrices $A$ and $B$ are both sparse and in fact have nonzero elements in exactly the same positions.)

*Clarification.* By "more efficient" I really mean the practical side: in a problem I am thinking about, the numbers $p$ and $q$ are in hundreds (and there are many pairs $(A,B)$ for which I have a conjecture that needs to be checked), which makes computations unpleasantly slow.

*Context:* I asked a question about algorithms for Smith normal forms some days ago both on MO and elsewhere, and was (justly) pointed out that simultaneous cross-posting is not appropriate, so I ended up choosing the SciComp as a place to ask it  ([this is the question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/42047/software-for-smith-form-or-hermite-form-of-a-sparse-polynomial-matrix?noredirect=1#comment82335_42047)). Answering a comment to that question, I realised that the matter of generic rank is what I care to understand the most, and I suspect that if this part of the question can be answered somewhere, that'd be on MathOverflow.

Comment: Are you happy with a probabilistic algorithm? If so, choosing random values of $t$ and row reducing should work with high probability, right?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan that does not make me *completely* happy but is definitely worth considering, thanks!

Comment: You can also work (this is how I usually do) modulo a "random" prime number $\ell$ (say with 3 or 4 digits) and one "random" value of $t$. The advantage of working modulo $\ell$ is that you avoid producing large entries/denominators. If the rank is indeed $r$, this will quite likely provide the answer $r$ (which certifies the expected rank is $\ge r$), and you can repeat the request with other values only if it provides rank $<r$.

Comment: @YCor this might help a lot, thanks! (Due to many situations where I work with $S_n$-modules, I tend to ignore the usefulness of modular arithmetic even where it is useful!!)